# Issue with writing htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

Please guys I need help; I am having a little issue routing my URL using .htaccess.

I want a situation where I can route the url Localhost/project_folder/test/learn-the-basic-of-computing to a script on my server. Like Localhost/project_folder/test/learn-the-basic-of-computing should be routed to script.php where the slug "learn-the-basic-of-computing" will be use as a URL parameter.

So I want Localhost/project_folder/test/learn-the-basic-of-computing to be routed to script.php?slug="learn-the-basic-of-computing".

Please can someone recommend solutions on how I will construct the .htaccess rules to achieve the above explained situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Please place .htaccess inside `project_folder/test/` directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  script.php?slug=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

***Brief explanation:*** By using `(.*)` save matched regex value into buffer where it will match `learn-the-basic-of-computing` and later using in redirection as query string by using `$1`.